# Is this patent still valid? Application deemed to be withdrawn

Tags: application, withdrawn

I am looking to add a product to my online business but want to make sure I am not infringing any patents.

EP1552050 - SUPPORT DEVICE FOR FABRIC ITEMS SUCH AS CURTAINS

Status: The application is deemed to be withdrawn

Does this mean that the patent has been annulled?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at this, but according to [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadoc?CC=EP&NR=1552050A2&KC=A2&FT=D&ND=3&date=20050713&DB=&locale=en_EP), the status was "APPLICATION DEEMED TO BE WITHDRAWN" as of 2010/07/07. I believe this means the application never became a patent and thus doesn't need to be annulled.

While this application does not seem to be an issue, I caution that this doesn't mean that there aren't other patents that might be. For instance [FR2845583 (B1)](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadoc?CC=FR&NR=2845583B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=5&date=20050701&DB=&locale=en_EP) looks like it might have issued in France, but looks like it has lapsed. Also there may be prior art to these patents which are relevant. As always, I suggest it is most prudent to have a professional freedom to operate analysis done.